# Why do setpci and lspci -xxxx show different data for the same address?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver, device-driver, pci-e

On my x86 Linux system reading from different locations in PCI configuration space using `setpci` seems to give completely different answers for some registers when compared to output from `lspci -xxxx`.

For example, I pick an arbitrary device on my bus and do `lspci -s 00:1f.3 -xxxx` and get:

```
00: 86 80 22 1e 03 00 80 02 04 00 05 0c 00 00 00 00
10: 04 40 51 d0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20: a1 ef 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 10 8b 05
```

...

```
e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 87 0f 04 08 00 00 00 00
```

Now, the output from `setpci -s 00:1f.3 0x40+0.l` is `02800003` which is consistent with the output above. However, the output from `setpci -s 00:1f.3 0xf8+0.l` is `ffffffff` which from the dump above I would have expected to be `08040f87`.

Can someone please help shed some light on what is going on here. I'm new to the world of PCI debugging, so I may be missing something obvious here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be asked on http://superuser.com/

Comment: I don't think this would be any less OT on superuser.com. If there is a Stackoverflow for embedded systems development I'm missing that may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## man setpci

setpci is a utility for querying and configuring PCI devices.

Root  privileges are necessary for almost all operations, excluding reads of the standard header of the configuration space on some operating systems. Please see lspci(8) for details on access rights.

Try as a Super-user

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that! Thanks.